# Hide div inside table

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to hide `div 2` and `div 3`. 
But it is not working.
it works only after I pull the div out of the table. Can anyone explain to me why?

**Script**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#2").hide();
            $("#3").hide();
            });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
  <div align="center">
  <table width="10%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
        <div id = "1">
          <th><input type = "button" value = "1.1" ></th>
          <th><input type = "button" value = "1.2" ></th>
          <th><input type = "button" value = "1.3" ></th>
        </div>
        <div id = "2">
            <th><input type = "button" value = "2.1" ></th>
            <th><input type = "button" value = "2.2" ></th>
            <th><input type = "text" value = "2.3" ></th>
        </div>
        <div id = "3">
            <th><input type = "button" value = "3.1" ></th>
            <th><input type = "button" value = "3.2" ></th>
        </div>
        </tr>
      </table></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are not using HTML5, `id` attributes cannot start with numbers. Try using another identifier, such as `el2`.

*Update*
Actually, the problem is because `div` elements are not valid in a `tr`, so the browser is removing them, hence the `#2` selector finds nothing to hide. The best alternative is to add a class to each `th` you need to hide and use CSS to hide them.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GcW4h/)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you give the `<TH>` elements a css class and hide them, instead of introducing DIVs in the middle of a table, e.g:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".th2").hide();
        $(".th3").hide();
        });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div align="center">
<table width="10%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
  <th scope="row"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <th class="th1"><input type = "button" value = "OP / FE" ></th>
      <th class="th1"><input type = "button" value = "LS" ></th>
      <th class="th1"><input type = "button" value = "FLX" ></th>
      <th class="th2"><input type = "button" value = "2.1" ></th>
      <th class="th2"><input type = "button" value = "2.2" ></th>
      <th class="th2"><input type = "text" value = "2.3" ></th>
      ...
    </tr>
  </table></th>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please change Div to table and add jqury.js link  to page and test it :
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $("#div2").hide();
        $("#div3").hide();
    });
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div align="center">
  <table width="10%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
        <table id = "div1">
          <th><input type = "button" value = "1.1" ></th>
          <th><input type = "button" value = "1.2" ></th>
          <th><input type = "button" value = "1.3" ></th>
        </table>
        <table id = "div2">
            <th><input type = "button" value = "2.1" ></th>
            <th><input type = "button" value = "2.2" ></th>
            <th><input type = "text" value = "2.3" ></th>
        </table>
        <table id = "div3">
            <th><input type = "button" value = "3.1" ></th>
            <th><input type = "button" value = "3.2" ></th>
        </table>
        </tr>
      </table></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```